# Android : org json jsonexception no value for

Tags: android-fragments, jsonexception

i use this json url :
https://www.theaudiodb.com/api/v1/json/1/search.php?s=coldplay

```
{
"artists": [
    {
        "idArtist": "111239",
        "strArtist": "Coldplay",
        "strArtistStripped": null,
        "strArtistAlternate": "",
        "strLabel": "Parlophone",
        "idLabel": "45114",
        "intFormedYear": "1996",
        "intBornYear": "1996",
        "intDiedYear": null,
        "strDisbanded": null,
        "strStyle": "Rock/Pop",
        "strGenre": "Alternative Rock",
         etc
}
```

and this is my android java code :

```
    void syncToUrl() {
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    String url = "https://www.theaudiodb.com/api/v1/json/1/search.php?s=coldplay";

    client.get(url, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {
            parseAndShow(responseString);

        }
    });
}
void parseAndShow(String responce) {
    try {
        JSONObject artistBio = new JSONObject(responce);

        artistNickname.setText(artistBio.getString("strArtist"));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Error.setText(e.toString());
    }
}
```

But I still get this Error:
org.json.jsonexception no value for strArtist.

The strArtist has this value "Coldplay", but why do I get this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value of `strArtist` as follows:

```
JSONObject artistBio = new JSONObject(responce);
JSONArray artists = artistBio.getJSONArray("artists");

for (int i=0; i < artists.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject object = artists.getJSONObject(i);
  String name = actor.getString("strArtist");
  artistNickname.setText(artistBio.getString("strArtist"));
}
```

**EDIT**

Since your json has only one object inside the array, you can skip the for loop implementation and directly use as follows:

```
JSONObject object = artists.getJSONObject(0);
String name = actor.getString("strArtist");
artistNickname.setText(artistBio.getString("strArtist"));
```

Comment: I will but I just want to know how does it waste CPU cycles?

Comment: 1. Allocation of stack variable.  2. artists.Length() method call. 3. Subtract for comparison. 4. Run loop(no difference.)  5.  Increment variable.  6. artists.Length() method call. 7. Subtract for comparison. End loop.  With the exception of step 4, the rest are wasteful.  To summarize: 1 addition 2 subtractions, 2 method calls, and one variable allocation on the stack.

Comment: It is minor but it adds up, especially on mobile devices. The foreach eliminates the comparisons and is much more efficient, almost  1/2 of the overhead of a for loop, less for larger collections.